# How to make unit tests for a methods in complicated class in python?

Tags: python, class, testing, initialization, python-unittest

I would like to create unit test for filename_to_txt method:

```
class some_panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,Some_class,some_handler,Some_Event):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.some_handler = some_handler
        self.some_Event = Some_Event
        self.some_another_class = Some_class

    def filename_to_txt(self,input_filename):
        splitted = input_filename.split(".raw")
        txt_filename  = splitted[0] + splitted[1] + ".txt"
        return txt_filename
```

How should I write unit test for that method?

It is static method in some class, but to test that firstly I have to make and instance of Some_panel class.

Do I really have to provide all arguments for __init__ method of Some_panel class?? Is there another better approach, for which I don't have to make an instance of that Some_panel class to test  filename_to_txt method.

```
import unittest
from some_file import Some_panel

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def testname(self):
        some_panel = Some_panel( ???? )
        testfilename = "TestFilename.raw.001"
        result = some_panel.filename_to_txt(input_filename = testfilename)
        self.assertEqual(result, "TestFilename.001.txt", "Something is wrong")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static method, remove the `self` argument and decorate it with the `@staticmethod` decorator. You can then call it as a pure function using `some_panel.filename_to_text(filename)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But what if I can't change source? 
Is this correct approach to create new class which inherit from Some_panel class and override __init__ method just to pass?

Comment: If you can't change the source then calls to `some_panel.filename_to-text` will demand an instance of `some_panel` )or a subclass thereof) as a first argument, so you have no option but to create an instance and then call the method on that. The subclass will inherit `__init__()` unless it defines its own. If it does that, then it will need to call `some_panel.__init__()` explicitly - preferably through use of `super`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to stub out the SomePanel class.

```
class SomePanelStub(SomePanel):
  def __init__(self):
    self.parent = None
    self.some_handler = None
    self.some_Event = None
    self.some_another_class = None
```

Now inside your unittest Class

```
def SetUp(self):
  self.helper = SomePanelStub()
```

Now you have stubbed out SomePanel and can easily mock out any dependencies.